# How to show that there are no solutions without solving? [simultaneous]

Tags: systems-of-equations, intuition, quadratics

$21x + 6y = k$

$(7x-20)^2 + (6y+10)^2 = 200$

if $k = 1$ , how to explain there are no solutions without solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x' = 7x, y' = 6y$, the the equations become
$3 x'+y'=1$, $(x'-20)^2+(y'+10)^2 = 200$.

The distance from the centre $(20,-10)$ to the line is ${49 \over \sqrt{10}}$ and the radius is $10 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: is there another way to do this without graphs?

Comment: How do graphs come in to it? If every point in the line is more than a radius away, the line cannot intersect the circle and so there is no solution.